# What is that square bomb you plant on doors before breaching into a room and going into bullet time?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Before you and your comrades breach into a room to save a prisoner and enter bullet time to kill off some guards, you will almost-always place a large, flat, square bomb on the door.

Q1: What is that large, flat, square bomb called?

Q2: Unlike C4, why can you stand right in front of & beside the square bomb without taking any damage? The people on the other side (which is blocked by a door) seems to be in great shock, but not you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a [breaching charge](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Breaching_charge).  I believe in the CoD series they tend to use "Frame Charges" for breaching.  It's used specifically for explosive [door breaching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door_breaching).  A breaching charge is a type of [shaped charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaped_charge), which focuses the force of a blast in a specific direction in order to accomplish a specific purpose.